# Does os.fork() pick up where it left off?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a function where certain data is being processed, and if the data meets a certain criteria, it's to be handled separate while the rest of the data is being processed.

As an arbitrary example if I'm scraping a web page and collecting all the attributes of an element, one of the elements is a form and just so happens to be hidden, I want to handle it separate, while the rest of the elements can continue being processed:

```
def get_hidden_forms(element_att):
    if element_att == 'hidden':
        os.fork()
        # handle this seperate
    else:
        # continue handling any elements that are not hidden
    #join both processes
```

Can this be done with os.fork() or is it intended for another purpose?

I know that os.fork() copies everything about the object, but I could just change values before forking, as stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461548/how-to-pass-arguments-to-processes-created-by-fork).

Comment: Anything against using the `multiprocessing` module? Why go all the way down to `os.fork()`?

Comment: @yorodm No, I have nothing against the multiprocessing module, I'm not sure what led you to think that, but after reading the docs on the module I just thought that os.fork() would probably suit my needs a little better.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant by "anything against it" (a.k.a doesn't work for you)

Comment: @aeaglez I'm with yorodm on this one; `os.fork` is really low-level by python standards, and it usually exists to fill a specific niche. `multiprocessing` offers a saner API built on top of the `fork` API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fork` basically creates a clone of the process calling it with a new address space and new PID.

From that point on, both processes would continue running next instruction after the `fork()` call. For this purpose, you normally inspect it's return value and decide what is appropriate action. If it return `int` greater than `0`, it's the PID of child process and you know you are in its parent... you continue parents work. If it's equal to `0`, you are in a child process and should do child's work. Value less then `0` means `fork` has failed, Python would handle that and raise `OSError` which you should handle (you're still in and there only is a parent).

Now the absolute minimum you'd need to take care of having forked a child process is to also make sure you `wait()` for them and reap their return codes properly, otherwise you will (at least temporarily) create zombies. That actually means you may want to implement a `SICHLD` handler to reap your process' children remains as they are done with their execution.

In theory you could use it the way you've described, but it may be a bit too "low level" (and uncomfortable) for that and perhaps would be easier to do and read/understand if you had dedicated code for what you want to handle separately and use [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) to handle running this extra work in separate processes.

Comment: There is dedicated code for it, the only thing I'm contemplating is how they would join together in one process again. For multiprocessing I could just spawn a new process, keep my current one running, and before the critical section is over, join them? Would that suffice?

Comment: Short version is yes. [`.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join) would wait for the other process to finish (if it has not done so in the meanwhile). Unless you really need the low-level control, I'd prefer comfort of greater abstraction which should allow for simpler code.